# Company checkin status not registered

Tags: laravel-5

I hit an api on postman when firstly hit an api it update the company checkin status but not show on postman it show empty array of company Checkin. after when i secondly hit an api it shows the checkin status array. Please help. Thanks in Advance

```
public function checkinCompany(Company $company)
{
    if (! $this->isCheckedinCompany($company))
    {
        return $this->checkinCompanies()->attach($company);            
    }
}

  public function isCheckedinCompany(Company $company)
  {
     return !! CompanyCheckin::where('company_id', $company->id)- >where('user_id', $this->id)->count();
  }
```

I want this to shoe company checkin array on first hit

Comment: The attach method always returns NULL.

Comment: Any other method except Attach ? @Jo